# buffer I/O error & print_req_error dev xvda

Tags: raid, citrix

We are seeing alot of "Buffer I/O error on device xvda2, logical block xxxxx" and "print_req_error: I/O error, dev xvda, sector xxxxxx" on two VM's running Ubuntu 18.04.3 and soon after that we see filesystem to remount as read only causig the VM to crash.

These VM’s are originally created in XenServer 7.2. and migrated now to Citrix Hypervisor 8.2. Xen Guest tools have been upgraded to 8.2. level. These errors appeared after migrating the VM to Citrix Hypervisor 8.2

The HW diagnostics does not show any errors on the array controller or on the disks.

What could cause this kind of behaviour? Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Reference information about the environment:

Hypervisor:

- Citrix Hypervisor 8.2. (Build date 2021-07-28, DBV 2020.0617)

Hardware:

- HP Proliant ML350 Gen10
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4210 CPU @ 2.20GHz (System ROM U41 v2.42 (01/23/2021))
- HPE Smart Array P408i-a SR Gen10 (FW version 3.53)
- 4x2.4TB SAS HDD RAID10 configuration

VM:

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Linux 4.15.0-158-generic x86_64)

Comment: Is this a Citrix or Ubuntu question?

Comment: Ubuntu, as we are seeing these errors on a Ubuntu VM